# Features to include on a new embedded Linux board to make development and debug easier?

Tags: arm, embedded, linux, bsp

At my work we're planning on developing a new ARM based embedded Linux board. I want to give the hardware guys some guidance on features they could add that would make the software development easier. My list so far is:

```
At least one dual/tri color LED controllable by GPO
A JTAG header
An extra serial port for debug log messages
Extra GPIOs taken out to a header for monitoring by logic analyzer etc.
```

Can anyone suggest any features they found they later needed that would have helped if present on an initial board?

Comment: A board-is-powered LED. A heartbeat LED. The latter should be updated somewhere in the normal program logic(not a timed interrupt), so if it is not flashing, the system is probably frozen. Possibly a scary red critical-error LED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list looks good. I'd add:

- some means of resetting the board other than de-powering it
- some means of recovering from bad firmware updates

Comment: For the recovery, it's hard to beat a mask ROM UART bootloader startup option.  Then no matter what someone does, it's recoverable unless the hardware is physically damaged, and unlike JTAG doesn't need any specialized equipment.